# restoring a caret position

Tags: javascript, parsing, range

I'm trying to use rangy to save a caret position before I highlight some text. But, I think since I'm inserting html that it's having problems restoring the caret. Here's the code:

```
var saved_selection = rangy.saveSelection( );

$( "#code" ).html( code_hl.highlight(   $( "#code" ).text( ),
                                        -1,
                                        -1 ) );

rangy.restoreSelection( saved_selection );
```

It keeps saying that the marker element has been removed. Is it not working because I'm inserting html?

<del>I'm wondering, alternatively, if I can set the caret by using the index of the caret by itself. There's another object I wrote, kb_input, that keeps track of the caret position, offset in the current line, and the current line number. So, I'm wondering if that might also be of help.</del>

If someone could help me understand the relationship between the a caret position in a contenteditable tag and ranges, that would be enough to get me going.

Comment: I wrote the code_hl object, only what's inside of "code" is altered. is that what you mean?

Comment: I reread your question and realized my [now-deleted] comment was off. If you alter `innerHTML` or `innerText/textContent`, then you lose all the child nodes, which I think is what's going on here.

Comment: okay, now at least I know why it's not working

Comment: You might look at how [CodeMirror](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror) does things, because they have to deal with similar issues.

Comment: I did, the 5000 lines of code was kind of overwhelming lol

Comment: haha - yeah, I'd imagine. I looked through a bit too - I think they base everything on line number and column number, so you can always do the selection like that. (e.g. for a selection, store start and end position, then restore afterwards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Rangy 1.3 (still in alpha, but I'm working on it), you can use a character index-based approach instead, which avoids the need for inserting marker elements:

```
// Save the selection by character index
bookmark = rangy.getSelection().getBookmark(editableEl);

// Do stuff that changes the editable content...

// Restore the selection
rangy.getSelection().moveToBookmark(bookmark);
```

Demo: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/bookmark.html

Comment: I tried that, <del> but the caret will either fly all over the place or not move at all :/ </del> I'm still getting mixed results, let me make sure it's not other code causing the errors.

Comment: I think the only issues are is that I can no longer enter new lines and i'm having trouble with the parser I wrote ( both still work on a copy page ).

Comment: your library works fine, I found out the bugs i'm experiencing are from switching to contenteditable. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One part of the answer to your question is that `jQuery.html` removes all content that was previously inside the element (just like the `innerHTML` property of DOM elements).  Snippet from [the jQuery docs on `jQuery.html(htmlString)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was
>   in that element is completely replaced by the new content.
>   Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event
>   handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the
>   new content.